# Exception calling "FindOne" with "0" argument(s): "The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist

Tags: powershell, exception, invoke-command

I am attempting to validate the OU of a remote computer in an Invoke session. The code works outside of the script block, but tanks when run within the script block on the remote machine... o_O

This works:

```
$rootDse = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE")
$Domain = $rootDse.DefaultNamingContext 
$root = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$Domain") 
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME 
$searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($root) 
$searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(name=$ComputerName))" 
[System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult]$result = $searcher.FindOne() 
$dn = $result.Properties["distinguishedName"] 
$ouResult = $dn.Substring($ComputerName.Length + 4) 

$ouResult
```

And this does not (returns error in title)

```
#$VMname = Read-Host -Prompt "What server do you want to validate? "
$VMname = "ObsfucatedHostNameHere"
#$Domain = Read-Host -Prompt "What domain is it in (Please specify complete domain)? "
$Domain = "ObsfucatedDomainNameHere.com"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "$VMname.$Domain" -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock { param($VMname)

$rootDse = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE")
$Domain = $rootDse.DefaultNamingContext 
$root = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$Domain") 
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME 
$searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($root) 
$searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(name=$ComputerName))" 
[System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult]$result = $searcher.FindOne() 
$dn = $result.Properties["distinguishedName"] 
$ouResult = $dn.Substring($ComputerName.Length + 4) 

$ouResult 
}
```

Comment: Sounds like [double hop](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/). Easiest way here is probably pass the creds and use a different overload for the [DirectoryEntry Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2h7eed(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ok... That sounds like something that would totally work. The only problem is, I only half understand that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting a chance to double check this, this is a case of the double hop problem. When you use `Invoke-Command` you aren't able to connect to yet another server using the credentials in the `Invoke-Command`. But there are some workarounds to this. The best being Resourced-Base constrained Delegation, which [Ashley McGlone has several articles on](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/) along with the other workarounds, but where that doesn't work you can just bundle up the credentials that you want to use and pass them inside the scriptblock.

Here an example of this applied to your code:

```
#$VMname = Read-Host -Prompt "What server do you want to validate? "
$VMname = "ObsfucatedHostNameHere"
#$Domain = Read-Host -Prompt "What domain is it in (Please specify complete domain)? "
$Domain = "ObsfucatedDomainNameHere.com"

$Cred = (Get-Credential)
$Username = $Cred.UserName
$Password = $Cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "$VMname.$Domain" -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock { 
    $rootDse = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE",$using:Username,$using:Password)
    $Domain = $rootDse.DefaultNamingContext 
    $root = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$Domain",$using:Username,$using:Password) 
    $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME 
    $searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($root) 
    $searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(name=$ComputerName))" 
    [System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult]$result = $searcher.FindOne() 
    $dn = $result.Properties["distinguishedName"] 
    $dn.Substring($ComputerName.Length + 4) 
}
```

I maybe a couple other clean up changes too. You weren't using VMname after you paramed it so I dropped out `param($VMname)`. (Note that if you are using PowerShell 2, you'll need to use the param rather than scoping with `$using`. And I also dropped out `$ouResult` as you could just output without the extra step of defining a extra variable.

Comment: Wow. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you super, extremely, very much...

Comment: Sorry, acidentally deleted the comment...It is very possible I missed something, but I get the error:Cannot index into a null array. + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray + PSComputerName : xxx You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull + PSComputerName : xxx

Comment: @MarcEverlove So the only array index you have is `$result.Properties["distinguishedName"]`, so that means that there were no results when you searched the directory for that computer object. Then since `$dn` is `$null` then you couldn't use the substring method. So I would check if a computer object `xxx` exists in that AD domain